# How to find a string from multiple .csv files

Tags: cygwin

I have multiple .csv files in a folder named HW in my desktop and I am using cygwin , I want to find a string from a specific column for example in X column ARD is the header in content value may be true or false , I want to find the count of ARD=true.

Please help me...

Comment: are the columns sorted? I.e. do you know if the header key word is always in column number x?

Answer (score 3):

Simple if the keyword is always in the same column, e.g. column number 2

```
cut -d, -f 2 file(s) | grep -c 'true'
```

i.e. cut out column 2 (-f 2), using "," as field seperator ( -d, ), get (grep) all trues and count them (-c)

more complicated, if we have to search for column "ARD"

```
awk  'BEGIN {FS = ","}  ; FNR == 1 { for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ ) { if ( $i=="ARD" ) { col=i } } } ; FNR >= 2 { print $col }' file(s) | grep -c 'true'
```

1) `BEGIN { FS = "," }`before every action (BEGIN) use comma `","` as field seperator ( `FS=` )

2) for first line (i.e. header line) of this file ( `FNR == 1` ) for all columns (`for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ )` ) check if the string "ARD" is in this column ( `if ( $i=="ARD")` ) ; if so , set the variable `col` to the number of this column `{ col=i }`

3) now that we know the number of our column print the column omitting the first (=header) line (i.e. all rows grater than 2) of this file `FNR >= 2 { print $col }` . here we use the variable `col` as defined before.

4) pipe the output through `grep` counting ( `-c` ) the occurrences of "true"

5) for a file-by-file listing, use a for loop in a bash scrip

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 3 files:

`new.csv`

```
Col1,Col2,ARD,Col4
1,2,true,3
1,2,true,3
1,2,true,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
```

`new1.csv` :

```
Col1,Col2,ARD,Col4
1,2,true,3
1,2,true,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
```

`new2.csv`:

```
Col1,Col2,ARD,Col4
1,2,true,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
1,2,false,3
```

#### Do:

`awk -F',' '{print $3}' *.csv | grep -c true`

#### Output:

6

Assumption:

1. The **ARD** is always on the same column (column 3 in the example)
2. You want to `grep` through all the `*.csv` files in that directory

Comment: you probably want to change your `grep -c false` to `grep -c true` since the asker is looking for the instances of true, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using **awk** to split the line and then

```
grep TRUE | wc -l
```

to count the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep recursively for all the content in the directory by

```
cd /path/to/dir/*
grep -r "ARD"
```

or simply

```
grep -r -l "ARD" /path/to/dir/*
```

Source for this :
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-recursively-search-all-files-for-words/

Also you can use awk for searching a csv file such as

```
awk -F, '$X == ARD' HW
```

X stand for the column number and ARD stands for your keyword and HW is your csv file above.

Source for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373885/searching-a-csv-file-using-grep

Also this would work as another option

```
grep '^\([^|]*|\)\{X\}ARD|' HW
```

Source for this : http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/123978-grepping-specific-column.html